# Dynamic insert sql stored procedure

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I have an issue regarding dynamic insert sql stored procedure because i need to insert an unknown amount (dynamically generated),

below is how it's written:

```
@Parameter as nvarchar(Max),
@SQLQuery as nvarchar(Max)

SET @SQLQuery = 'insert into <table>
(FieldOne,FieldTwo,FieldThree,GeneratedId,dateAdded,addedBy)
values '+@Parameter
EXEC sp_executesql @SQLQuery
```

When i try to execute this stored procedure using the below values:

```
@Parameter = (1,0,0,12345678123,"2016-03-22 23:26:25",123)
@SQLQuery = null
```

I even tried (for silly reasons) to try the below values:

```
@Parameter = (1,0,0,12345678123,2016-03-22 23:26:25,123)
@SQLQuery = null
```

I get the below Error from SQL Server

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>       Incorrect syntax near '23'.
>
> (1 row(s) affected)

But no rows are actually added.

The table i am using is as below:

```
ID           (PK and autoincrement)
FieldOne:    tinyint
FieldTwo:    tinyint
FieldThree:  tinyint
GeneratedId: nvarchar(50)
dateAdded:   datetime
addedBy:     int
```

I can't seem to figure out what i am doing wrong,

Thank you all in advance for your time and assistance.

Comment: What do you mean by, "I need to insert an unknown amount"? An unknown number of columns?

Comment: `@Parameter = (1,0,0,12345678123,''2016-03-22 23:26:2'',123)` Use double single quotes

Comment: Yes, In some point i might need (1,0,0,12345678123,"2016-03-22 23:26:25",123) While another time i might need (1,0,0,12345678123,"2016-03-22 23:26:25",123),(1,0,0,12345678124,"2016-03-22 23:26:26",123)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your date variable should be wrapped in single quotes, not double. Try that and it should work.

BUT.....

If you particularly want to go down this (unusual) road, I'd strongly suggest using the parameterised query support in sp_ExecuteSQL - it'll give you a better performing and usually more secure query.

Have a look https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx for more information on how to use sp_ExecuteSQL for parameterised queries.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the double quotes, be sure that QUOTED_IDENTIFIER is on
ie.
     SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;